# Is there any MySQL Compression plugin or tool available?

Tags: mysql

we undergoing performance based testing on MySQL,so we are seeking for MySQL compression tool for that purpose.If anyone came to acquainted about it please let me know..

Advance Thanks,

Comment: what exactly should be compressed?

Comment: You didn't mention anything about engine(s) you were planning to use. Two most popular engines (MyISAM and InnoDB) have already built-in compression control, and there's Archive engine that compresses the data. There are other engines (made for data warehousing) such as Infobright engine that also offer compression and excellent performance.

Comment: This isn't a good question. Please explain what type of compression you mean. What are you attempting to improve/compress?

Comment: Hi @James C I meant for MySQL Database compression.Got it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible answers:

1 For compressed data storage, you may want to look at MySQLs Archive storage engine

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/storage-engine.html

2 The compressed protocol can in some cases speed up communication between client and server

[When should I use MySQL compressed protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506460/when-should-i-use-mysql-compressed-protocol)

Comment: Hi @Michael J.V. We are presently using InnoDB Engine but we looking for an alternative....

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has built-in [`COMPRESS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_compress) and [`UNCOMPRESS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_uncompress) functions. That'd require you to change code and use VARBINARY or BLOB columns however. As well it'd only really be of value for large columns. I'm not otherwise aware of a plugin or tool to compress a whole MySQL database. You'll probably find better luck with file system compression like [ZFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) that you can use under MySQL. See [A look at MySQL on ZFS](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-zfs.html).