# MySQL fetch time too important

Tags: mysql

My query as a small duration time when the Fetch time is quite large. What is exactly the fetching time. Can it be reduced ? Is it dependent on the network since the server is a remote one.

my Query is a simple one 
`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id = a primary_Key;` 
Usually, the query returns between 5 and 50k rows.
But the table has 9 million Rows. The count(*) takes 82 seconds (duration) and 0 for fetching time.

Comment: one is how long it takes to get the requested data from the database itself, and the other is how long before that gets sent to the client.

Comment: If you query by a primary key, you should only get 1 record (or none), not between 5 and 50k rows...

Comment: You are right, there's an index on the column. My mistakes. but the question remains the same :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch time does depend on network speed. Your `SELECT Count(*) ...` query only returns a single number so network overhead is minimal.

To improve the speed, I suggest you only fetch the columns and rows you need (i.e. replace `SELECT * ...` with the exact columns you need).

Also, enabling compression between client and server will reduce time (but will slightly increase CPU usage for compressing/decompressing). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506460/when-should-i-use-mysql-compressed-protocol) related question.

Comment: Does it means that a way to reduce the time, is to make the database local on my computer ?

Comment: If this is an option, it will certainly improve fetch time by eliminating network time.

Answer (score -3):

Have you looked into using [Mysql Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: what to do with indices?